# WebClient errors under high load connecting to Firebase rest api

Tags: c#, rest, firebase

I am connecting to the Firebase REST API using C# WebClient. Sample:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
   webClient.UploadString(restUrl, "PATCH", jsonDataString);
}
```

Under a medium load it works great, but at some point I start to get this error (the error is throw immediately, no delay/timeout)

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

Many requests on the live server will get this error, while it is not possible to duplicate the error in the test environment. (simultaneous with errors on live)  It seems that WebClient is using a keep-alive connection, and on starting a new request, it finds that the connection is already closed, and throws an exception.

How should I fix this?

I could try turning off keep-alive, but that seems inefficient.

Might changing some sort of timeout on WebClient (maybe shorter) fix it?  What value should it be?

Add exception handling to re-try the request?

Comment: It helps if you share a minimal fragment of your code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: There are *lots* of reasons why this would happen, like the server restarted, server crashed, there was a momentary network partition, etc.  Are you asking what you need to do when it happens?

Comment: Typically when you're overloading a server, it is best to back off for a while and try again later. In addition, you might want to see if there is a way you can batch your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my calls to WebClient.UploadString() with a call to my own UploadString (below) that retries a failed/closed connection up to 3x, logs the failed attempt, and fails silently after the 3rd attempt.  (I could re-throw the error after the 3rd fail, but for my purposes a silent fail is better)

```
protected void UploadString(string address, string method, string data)
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        bool success = false;
        int tryCount = 0;

        while (!success && tryCount++ < 3)
        {
            try
            {
                webClient.UploadString(address, method, data);
                success = true;
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Log.Audit(1, tryCount, address, method);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the Audits, it never has to retry more than once.  My understanding is that the keep-alive connection gets closed by the remote end at some point, I get an instant fail the next time I try to send data on my end, the connection on my end is closed, and the re-try opens a new connection.

Comment: I don't think Firebase currently applies (documented) **rate limiting** to the REST API, but you might want to be on the lookout for status codes related to that. Retrying without a delay would typically not improve matters when the call fails for that reason.